# Youtube QR Code Generation UserScript not functioning

Tags: javascript, youtube, share, qr-code, userscripts

I'm trying to create a userscript that automatically adds a QR code image of the current url to the 'Share' menu on a youtube video page.

I know next to nothing of JavaScript, UserScript, HTML, etc.
But, this is what I have so far:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Youtube QR ShareLink 
// @description    Displays QR of youtube URL 
// @version        0.1
// @match          http://www.youtube.com/watch*
// @match          https://www.youtube.com/?*
// @match          http://www.youtube.com/?*
// @match          https://www.youtube.com/watch*
// @include        http://www.youtube.com/?*
// @include        http://www.youtube.com/watch*
// @include        https://www.youtube.com/?*
// @include        https://www.youtube.com/watch*
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    var shareDiv = document.getElementById('share-option-container ytg-box');
    var qrIMG = 'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chl=' + window.location.href + '&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chs=125x125';
    var img = document.createElement('qrcode');
    img.src=qrIMG;
    img.width=125;
    img.height=125;
    shareDiv.appendChild(img);
}());
```

Unsurprisingly, it doesn't work.
Could anyone please tell me what it is I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: This right here doesn't make sense: `'share-option-container ytg-box'` An `id` cannot have a space in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `document.getElementById` with a value that isn't the id of the box - it's a list of the classes for that element. To use a selector like that, you could do it with a couple of calls to `document.getElementsByClassName`, or you could use `document.querySelector('.share-option-container .ytg-box')`, or you could use jQuery to perform that selection.

Your second problem is that you're creating an element called 'qrcode', but you should be creating an `img` element.

You're revised code should look like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Youtube QR ShareLink 
// @description    Displays QR of youtube URL 
// @version        0.1
// @match          http://www.youtube.com/watch*
// @match          https://www.youtube.com/?*
// @match          http://www.youtube.com/?*
// @match          https://www.youtube.com/watch*
// @include        http://www.youtube.com/?*
// @include        http://www.youtube.com/watch*
// @include        https://www.youtube.com/?*
// @include        https://www.youtube.com/watch*
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    var shareDiv = document.querySelector('.share-option-container .ytg-box');
    var qrIMG = 'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chl=' + window.location.href + '&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chs=125x125';
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src=qrIMG;
    img.width=125;
    img.height=125;
    shareDiv.appendChild(img);
}());
```

Note that on YouTube, the element that you're grabbing doesn't exist until the share box is actually opened, so you'll need to actually handle opening the share box first before the rest of your code runs. I've tested this in my browser and the above code works well once the share box has been opened, but not before.

You can account for that by using a timer. Change the code to:

```
var shareBoxCheckInterval   = setInterval (AddQR_Code, 200);

function AddQR_Code () {
    var shareDiv    = document.querySelector ('.share-option-container .ytg-box');
    if (shareDiv) {
        var qrIMG   = 'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chl=' 
                    + window.location.href + '&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chs=125x125';
        var img     = document.createElement ('img');
        img.src     = qrIMG;
        img.width   = 125;
        img.height  = 125;
        shareDiv.appendChild (img);

        /*-- If you want to continually check for new share boxes, on the
            same page, comment out this next line.
        */
        clearInterval (shareBoxCheckInterval);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
But forgive me for being a horrible learner, how exactly did you go about opening the share box?
(or is it possible to make the script execute every time the sharebox is opened, rather than forcefully opening the sharebox itself?)

Comment: You could run the code, only when the sharebox is present by checking for it inside a timer.  I took the liberty of adding that tweak to this answer.

Comment: Rofl, you messed up mah youtubes! :P
It shows up properly, but now it creates a new image at every interval (with the last line commented out)
I should probably make it check if the image already exists in the sharebox.
Thanks for your help, anyway :)

Comment: Oh, i 'fixed' it by uncommenting that line.
Turns out it doesn't actually create a new sharebox every time, but just hides/shows it when you close it.
Once again, thank you!

Comment: This script is PERFECT for my Android :D

Permission to post as-is (with credits) to userscripts.org? =3

Comment: @MickeyXD, I believe it's kosher to post the code as long as you [attribute per the copyright terms](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).  Of course, it wouldn't *hurt* to Paypal me lots of money, too.  ;)